# Port Forwarding Not Working on Netgear R7000?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've been trying to port forward my SSH port to my Raspberry Pi for a while unsuccessfully, and until today I thought it was an issue with the RPi itself. However, I went to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it does not show my port 22 as open (going to probably change the port, but once I actually get port forwarding working). [This is what the port forward menu looks like in my router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K22wv.png). I've tried port 22, port 80, and just random ports as tests and none of them are ever shown as open. Is there anything else I have to do to get port forwarding working? I haven't really configured my router in any other way. I just have the router on default settings, getting the IP and DNS from my ISP and using a default MAC address. The only thing I could think of is maybe setting up a static IP but I don't think I have to do that. I'm not especially experienced with networking in general, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That little round thing at the beginning of the config, is that clickable? Asking because I had a router which allowed rules to be written and it had a checkbox for enabling or disabling? And the rule being disabled obviously makes it not work.

Comment: It's clickable, but it's only for checking which port forward entry you want to edit. [Image for reference](http://imgur.com/a/2izgu)

Comment: Ok. As for a static IP (or a reserved entry in the DHCP server)... no need for that as long as the address of the rPi is current. It will help in the long run if it changes and should be trivial to set up. Worth doing after you have things working.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I assumed. Do you have any idea how a static IP for a router works, instead of for the pi? Would that be necessary maybe?

Comment: Most 'routers' are multi-function devices with a modem, wireless accesspoint, switch, firewall and a dhcp server. Somewhere you have a range for DHCP requests in the DHC|P-servers config (e.g. assign 172.16.0.1 till 172.16.0.50). Those same screens usually also have an option for 'always give this IP to that MAC'. That seems the easiest to use. (assign an IP outside of what is normally assigned via DHCP, e.g. 172.16.0.51).